# Given list of files from directory, sort by mb from smallest to largest

Tags: python

The given functions are provided by:

```
filenames = [(f"file_{str(i+1).zfill(4)}.{random.choice(['.MP4','.JPG','.PNG','.AVI'])}", f {random.random()*100:.2f} MB") for i in range(20)]
random.shuffle(filenames)
filenames
```

I need to accomplish the following:

```
# Sort the file names in increasing order of file size and print
??
# sort the files with filenames 
??
```

With the question marks where I have to provide code. I tried

```
print(sorted(filenames, reverse=False))
```

Which sorted the files by their number, like file.001, instead of their size. I also tried:

```
import os, operator, sys
dirpath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
all_files = ( os.path.join(basedir, filename) for basedir, dirs, filenames in os.walk(dirpath) for filename in filenames   )
files_and_sizes = ( (path, os.path.getsize(path)) for path in all_files )
sorted_files_with_size = sorted( files_and_sizes, key = operator.itemgetter(1) )
print(sorted_files_with_size)
```

Which produced only [] with nothing in it. I haven't started the second one because I am still stuck in the first.

Comment: `print(sorted(filenames), reverse=False)` can't run for a start because `reverse` is not a valid argument to `print`. It's almost certainly a typo but I'd rather prefer that you checked your example code for mistakes like this first before posting the question. That's in addition to the unclosed string.

Comment: where was the typo? maybe that's my problem

Comment: The initialization of `filenames` has multiple bugs in it. You should check your source and correct them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
from numpy import random
filenames = [(f"file_{str(i+1).zfill(4)}.{random.choice(['.MP4','.JPG','.PNG','.AVI'])}, f {random.random()*100:.2f} MB") for i in range(20)]
random.shuffle(filenames)
```

filenames:

```
['file_0011..JPG, f 58.18 MB',
 'file_0013..MP4, f 77.25 MB',
 'file_0006..PNG, f 20.44 MB',
 'file_0016..PNG, f 67.31 MB',
 'file_0007..MP4, f 2.62 MB',
 'file_0018..MP4, f 45.86 MB',
 'file_0014..PNG, f 93.33 MB',
 'file_0005..JPG, f 5.70 MB',
 'file_0009..AVI, f 45.29 MB',
 'file_0015..JPG, f 12.80 MB',
 'file_0017..MP4, f 47.74 MB',
 'file_0010..AVI, f 37.97 MB',
 'file_0012..AVI, f 11.25 MB',
 'file_0019..AVI, f 66.01 MB',
 'file_0001..JPG, f 26.32 MB',
 'file_0008..PNG, f 85.10 MB',
 'file_0020..PNG, f 52.03 MB',
 'file_0003..AVI, f 87.62 MB',
 'file_0004..PNG, f 37.04 MB',
 'file_0002..JPG, f 93.97 MB']
```

```
[' '.join(line) for line in sorted(list(map(str.split, filenames)), key=lambda x:float(x[2]))]
```

```
file_0007..MP4,     f 2.62 MB
file_0005..JPG,      f 5.7 MB
file_0012..AVI,    f 11.25 MB
file_0015..JPG,     f 12.8 MB
file_0006..PNG,    f 20.44 MB
file_0001..JPG,    f 26.32 MB
file_0004..PNG,    f 37.04 MB
file_0010..AVI,    f 37.97 MB
file_0009..AVI,    f 45.29 MB
file_0018..MP4,    f 45.86 MB
file_0017..MP4,    f 47.74 MB
file_0020..PNG,    f 52.03 MB
file_0011..JPG,    f 58.18 MB
file_0019..AVI,    f 66.01 MB
file_0016..PNG,    f 67.31 MB
file_0013..MP4,    f 77.25 MB
file_0008..PNG,     f 85.1 MB
file_0003..AVI,    f 87.62 MB
file_0014..PNG,    f 93.33 MB
file_0002..JPG,    f 93.97 MB
```

Comment: No need for numpy. Simpler and better to use standard Python random import, no?

Comment: It doesn't seem odd to either of you that the filenames have multiple periods and there's a random letter `f` in each line of output?

Comment: @jarmod the `f` and `MB` both are same for all values, and should be removed, since it in data so i don't remove it.

Comment: I'm just saying that the poster should resolve the issues inherent in the initialized `filenames`. And then solve the problem, because the solution code will change.